# Core Data Code=134110 "Cannot migrate store in-place: I/O error for database at ..."

Tags: ios9, core-data-migration

I added a new model version to my core data model, now I get this error when updating from the previous app version.

I'm additionally irritated as in the error it also says `SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: ZSOMECOLUMN'` as I didn't change anything about that recently.

The sqlite file is in the shared app container, may that be a reason for this?

**EDIT**

This seems to be specific to iOS 9.x, I don't experience this problem in iOS 8.x

Comment: Any udpate on this? @swalkner

Answer (score 2):

Do you by any chance happen to have multiple persistent stores?

I recently came across the same problem - lightweight migration worked on the main persistent store but failed on the secondary one that was using a different configuration.

I suspect there is a bug somewhere in CoreData that is causing this.

Comment: yes, I do indeed have multiple (= 2) persistent stores. Is there a way to fix this or a workaround? I mean, I need to handle this somehow, right?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to really investigate the cause of this. I've put in a workaround by deleting the database, putting a fresh one in place and re-syncing the data. This worked even though I used the same version of the data model as previous.